# Kotlin app crashes after button press with NullPointerException

Tags: android, kotlin, button, nullpointerexception, fragment

I am making a Kotlin app in Android Studio where I can add foods with their calorie values like a list.

How it is supposed to work is that the two EditText components, "etName" and "etCalories", would be passed into a list, then the TextView inside the RecyclerView should show them.

The issue is, if I press the button to add the item, the app crashes.

Here's the logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.bbar, PID: 25930
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.bbar.ui.home.FoodlistadapterKt.getBinding(foodlistadapter.kt:16)
        at com.example.bbar.ui.home.FoodlistadapterKt.access$getBinding(foodlistadapter.kt:1)
        at com.example.bbar.ui.home.Foodlistadapter.onBindViewHolder(foodlistadapter.kt:57)
        at com.example.bbar.ui.home.Foodlistadapter.onBindViewHolder(foodlistadapter.kt:18)
```

Here's the code

**foodlistadapter.kt**

```
package com.example.bbar.ui.home

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.bbar.R
import android.graphics.Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
import android.widget.TextView
import com.example.bbar.databinding.FooditemBinding


@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private var _binding: FooditemBinding? = null
private val binding get() =  _binding!!

class Foodlistadapter(

    private val foods: MutableList<food>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Foodlistadapter.foodlistviewholder>() {

    class foodlistviewholder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): foodlistviewholder {
        return foodlistviewholder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_home,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

     fun addFood(food: food) {
        foods.add(food)
        notifyItemInserted(foods.size - 1)
    }

     fun deleteFood() {
        foods.removeAll { foods -> foods.isChecked }
        notifyDataSetChanged()

    }

    private fun toggleStrikeThrough(tvFood: TextView, isChecked: Boolean) {
        if (isChecked) {
            tvFood.paintFlags = tvFood.paintFlags or STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
        } else {
            tvFood.paintFlags = tvFood.paintFlags or STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: foodlistviewholder, position: Int) {
        val currentFood = foods[position]
        holder.itemView.apply {
            binding.tvFood.text = currentFood.name
            binding.tvCalories.text= currentFood.calories.toString()
            binding.cbDelete.isChecked = currentFood.isChecked
            toggleStrikeThrough(binding.tvFood, currentFood.isChecked)
            binding.cbDelete.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                toggleStrikeThrough(binding.tvFood, isChecked)
                currentFood.isChecked = !currentFood.isChecked
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return foods.size
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.bbar.ui.home

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.bbar.R

import com.example.bbar.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding



class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var foodlistadapter: Foodlistadapter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        return binding!!.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        foodlistadapter = Foodlistadapter(mutableListOf())
        binding.rvFoodItems.adapter = foodlistadapter
        binding.rvFoodItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        binding.bSubmit.setOnClickListener{
            val foodTitle= binding.etName.text.toString()
            val foodCalories = binding.etCalories.text.toString()
            if (foodTitle.isNotEmpty()){
                val food= food(foodTitle, foodCalories.toInt(), false )
                foodlistadapter.addFood(food)
                binding.etName.text.clear()
                binding.etCalories.text.clear()
            }
        }
        binding.bDelete.setOnClickListener{
            foodlistadapter.deleteFood()
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Summary: Tried to add food with its respected calorie value with a button, but program crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `binding` is null & also it isn't used correctly.
First of, remove the declaration outside the class i.e:

```kotlin
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private var _binding: FooditemBinding? = null
private val binding get() =  _binding!!
```

Change your `ViewHolder` implementation to:

```kotlin
class FoodListViewHolder(val binding: FooditemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
```

Inflate that binding in `onCreateViewHolder`:

```kotlin
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FoodListViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    return FoodListViewHolder(FooditemBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false))
}
```

Use the binding in `onBindViewHolder`:

```kotlin
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FoodListViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentFood = foods[position]

    holder.binding.apply {
        tvFood.text = currentFood.name
        tvCalories.text= currentFood.calories.toString()
        cbDelete.isChecked = currentFood.isChecked
        toggleStrikeThrough(tvFood, isChecked)
        cbDelete.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            toggleStrikeThrough(tvFood, isChecked)
            currentFood.isChecked = !currentFood.isChecked
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This finally solved my problem. I'm going to have to delve deeper into Kotlin to understand it better, these parts are still new to me, but your help seems to make it easier to get the hang of it.